# MVC Javascript DateTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been developing a new website and have come across a strange datetime problem which I cannot seem to work out what is wrong.

My staging server is here: [Link](http://taxiroutemvc.azurewebsites.net/)

As you can see, people can enquire about taxis "Now" or in the "Future".

What *should* happen is that if you chose "Future" and put in a date/time more than 2 hours ahead then I will be able to give you live quotes for taxis. If the lead time is less than 2 hours ahead then you should not see any "live" quotes.

I am developing it based on an API from a company in Finland and they have been testing it as well.

The guys in Finland are reporting that even when they select "Now" they are still getting live quotes when they shouldn't.

I use some JavaScript to populate the datetime selectors on the page like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours(); // this is in 24 hour
var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

if (curr_minute < 15) { $("#enquiry_timeMins").val(15); }
if (curr_minute >= 15 && curr_minute < 30) { $("#enquiry_timeMins").val(30); }
if (curr_minute >= 30 && curr_minute < 45) { $("#enquiry_timeMins").val(45); }
if (curr_minute >= 45 && curr_minute < 59) { $("#enquiry_timeMins").val(00); curr_hour = curr_hour + 1; }

if (curr_hour >= 12) {
    $("#enquiry_timeAMPM").val("PM");
    $("#enquiry_timeHours").val(curr_hour - 12);
}
else {
    $("#enquiry_timeAMPM").val("AM");
    $("#enquiry_timeHours").val(curr_hour);
}

$("#enquiry_pickupTime").val(curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
```

and then in my controller I do this:

```
theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddHours(theRoute.enquiry.timeHours);
theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddMinutes(theRoute.enquiry.timeMins);
if (theRoute.enquiry.timeAMPM == "PM") { theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddHours(12); }
```

This seems to work perfectly for me but I'm based in the UK. The guys in Finland happen to be 2 hours ahead as well. Which seems more than a coincidence as the lead time is also 2 hours ahead.

Can anyone see anything that I haven't considered that makes this work in the UK but not in Finland, and possibly other countries as well?

Comment: Won't the server side code, execute in your servers time zone where as the JavaScript will execute in the time zone of the browser, i.e. finland?

Comment: @Liam thanks for the reply. but I don't think that can be the answer.. the server side code does nothing based on the server date - it just adds the values of the hour and minutes to the date in the datepicker...

Answer (score 0):

Guess your theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime is created in another time zone.

Comment: i cant see that being the problem either. theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime is null and populated by the values sent in via the response...

Answer (score 0):

ok. I think ive fixed it...

this is what I have done.

I worked out I need to know the number of hours behind or in front the browser time is so I could subsequently work out how much I need to move forward/backward the enquiry time...

I found this gist to help me work out the time diff as well as day light saving times:

```
function getTimeZoneOffsetDST() {
    // NOTE: return new Date().getTimezoneOffset() is not enought !
    var today = new Date();
    // 2nd Sunday in March can't occur after the 14th :
    var dstBeg = new Date("March 14, " + today.getFullYear() + " 02:00:00");
    // 1st Sunday in November can't occur after the 7th :
    var dstEnd = new Date("November 07, " + today.getFullYear() + " 02:00:00");
    dstBeg.setDate(14 - dstBeg.getDay()); // Calculate second Sunday in March
    dstEnd.setDate(7 - dstEnd.getDay()); // Calculate first Sunday in November
    if (today >= dstBeg && today < dstEnd) { // isDST
        // e.g. for GMT+02:00 returns -120 !
        return today.getTimezoneOffset() + 60;
    }
    else {
        return today.getTimezoneOffset();
    }
}
```

a bit of jquery like this

```
$("#timeMinsOffset").val(getTimeZoneOffsetDST());
```

populates this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model2 => Model.enquiry.timeMinsOffset, new { id = "timeMinsOffset" })
```

back in the controller I now simply add the offset time as well like this:

```
// at this point theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime is a null DateTime
theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddHours(theRoute.enquiry.timeHours);
theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddMinutes(theRoute.enquiry.timeMins);
theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddMinutes(theRoute.enquiry.timeMinsOffset);
if (theRoute.enquiry.timeAMPM == "PM") { theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime = theRoute.enquiry.pickupTime.AddHours(12); }
```

obvious now I look back. newbs eh?

hope this helps anyone else out there!